# Is the sum of a shift operator and a compact operator is invertible?

Tags: operator-theory, compact-operators

Let $T$ be the right shift operator, that is, $T(x_1,x_2,\ldots)=(0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)$, suppose $E$ is a compact operator from $\ell^{\infty}\rightarrow \ell^{\infty}$, can $T+E$ be an invertible operator from $\ell^{\infty}\rightarrow \ell^{\infty}$? It seems that $T+E$ can not be invertible, but I could not prove this.

We know that $T$ and $E$ are not surjective operators, I tried to show that $T+E$ is not surjective so that it can not be invertible but failed.  Could some give any comments?

Comment: If $E=0$ then $T+E$ is certainly not surjective.

Comment: Here E is not 0. Then what is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$T+E$ will be a Fredholm operator with index -1, so it will not be invertible.

Comment: So you mean a Fredholm operator with index -1 is not invertible? Could you please give an explanation?   Is a  Fredholm operator with a negative index not invertible?

Comment: Every invertible operator has Fredholm index zero because both the dimension of the kernel and the codimension of the range are zero.

Comment: I got it, thank you for your help.